# iOS, Restarting animation when coming out of the background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-animation

when my app comes out of the background the animation has stopped. which is normal. but i want to restart my animation from the current state. how do i do that without my snapping all over the place.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:60 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{
    [bg setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1378, 1005)];
} completion:nil];
```

i tried putting a set frame in front of the animation but that just makes it snap.

```
[bg setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1378, 1005)];
```

any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Could you explain a bit about what kind of effect you expect form that code? I think that "current state" is the current state of running (in-progress) animation. And I suppose that CA Framework doesn't care about remembering the state where the animation was interrupted. Are you trying to write a cycling animation that can be stopped and restarted again from where it was stopped without playback to initial position?

Comment: hi. it's a kind of ken burns effect.

Comment: and the current state is the state the object is in at the moment. So it takes in account all the animation currently active on the object

Answer (score 28, accepted):

well the answer of @dany_23 could work.

But I came across an other method that works just fine if you don't need to resume your animation but restart your animation, without the view or layer snapping when you reactivate the app.

in the

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

you call a method in your viewcontroller which implements the following code.

```
[view.layer removeAllAnimations];
 // this following CGRect is the point where your view originally started 
[bg setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1378, 1005)];
```

and in the

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

you call a method in your viewcontroller that just starts the animation.
something like

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:60 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{
      [bg setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1378, 1005)];
} completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps, Thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 29):

You can add an observer in your class for UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification:

```
- (void)addNotifications { 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil]; 
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground { 
    [self animate]; 
}

- (void)animate { 
    [bg setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:60 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{
        [bg setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1378, 1005)];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

It is important to set the begin state of the animation (and don't forget to remove the notification observer)

Comment: _+1_ Notifications are better way to receive this kind of event, than using application delegate.

Comment: +1 This definitely is the more flexible and elegant solution for restarting looping animations. The UIApplicationDelegate shouldn't have to care about restarting MYWaitCycleView's spinning chicken animation. @Ramiro's code is perfectly happy sitting in a UIViewController or UIView subclass, close to the thing being animated.

Comment: I've used this method for years, but now ran into an issue where animations still stop and aren't restarted (they should be running indefinitely in my case); it happens when tapping the alert asking the user for approval of remote (and/or local) push alerts. I've yet to find a solution. Btw I use the notification `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` instead of `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`.

Comment: This worked but what I had to do was remove the CALayer (I used a gradientLayer) that had the animation and then add it all over again. Other then that my animation would pause when coming back to the foreground. I explained it at the bottom of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55883132/4833705

Answer (score 17):

There is a better soloution here than restarting whole animation each time you come from background.

For Swift 3 you can subclass this class:

```
class ViewWithPersistentAnimations : UIView {
    private var persistentAnimations: [String: CAAnimation] = [:]
    private var persistentSpeed: Float = 0.0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func didBecomeActive() {
        self.restoreAnimations(withKeys: Array(self.persistentAnimations.keys))
        self.persistentAnimations.removeAll()
        if self.persistentSpeed == 1.0 { //if layer was plaiyng before backgorund, resume it
            self.layer.resume()
        }
    }

    func willResignActive() {
        self.persistentSpeed = self.layer.speed

        self.layer.speed = 1.0 //in case layer was paused from outside, set speed to 1.0 to get all animations
        self.persistAnimations(withKeys: self.layer.animationKeys())
        self.layer.speed = self.persistentSpeed //restore original speed

        self.layer.pause()
    }

    func persistAnimations(withKeys: [String]?) {
        withKeys?.forEach({ (key) in
            if let animation = self.layer.animation(forKey: key) {
                self.persistentAnimations[key] = animation
            }
        })
    }

    func restoreAnimations(withKeys: [String]?) {
        withKeys?.forEach { key in
            if let persistentAnimation = self.persistentAnimations[key] {
                self.layer.add(persistentAnimation, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension CALayer {
    func pause() {
        if self.isPaused() == false {
            let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
            self.speed = 0.0
            self.timeOffset = pausedTime
        }
    }

    func isPaused() -> Bool {
        return self.speed == 0.0
    }

    func resume() {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = self.timeOffset
        self.speed = 1.0
        self.timeOffset = 0.0
        self.beginTime = 0.0
        let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
        self.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }
}
```

It will take care of pausing all your animations in current state and re-adding it when app comes from background - without resetting them.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/a5ed8b38bec548f9620bb95665c06128

Comment: This used to work well for me before, but at some point (maybe iOS 10?) I can't get the persisted animations to restore. Does anyone know what might have happened and if there's a solution for iOS 10 and later?

Comment: grteat point @JonatanLiljedahl

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to pause the animation when your app goes into the background and resume it when it becomes active again. You can find some sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1673/_index.html) that describes how to pause and resume an animation.

Answer (score 2):

Well if I understand the question right way, you're trying to create an animation and stop it in the middle.

In this case i would suggest you to use some kind of "state" variable to store the state of animation (the frame property for example). This variable you can use in further code to put the object that is being animated in correct position. This can be done in animationDidStop function ([animationDidStop:finished:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAAnimation)). In order to implement this function you will have to use the delegation. It means to set AppNameViewController (or some other unique object for entire application) as a delegate for an animation and write the implementation in its m-file. This will allow you to run "position setup" code at the end of the animation.

Next task is to store the animation state. While running animation, Core Animation framework creates a bunch of intermediate layers (presentation layers). And these layers are displayed during the animation and then they're deleted. And when animation finishes execution the object is just gets placed into it's final state. Actually you have to set this when you create so called "explicit animation" (and if you don't, animation will play but the object will jump back in the end). Each of these presentation layers has a set or it's own copy of all the properties that are called "animatable properties". When one of the animatable properties is set as a key for the animation, Core Animation calls [(BOOL)needsDisplayForKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) that returns YES/NO. It tells the Core Animation whether changes to the specified key required the layer to be redisplayed. To "redisplay" means to call [drawInContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) method for the presentation layer. Here you can grab the properties of the presentation layer that is currently displayed and put them into "state" variable.

The animation is played in thread and in order to set the "state" variable I used delegation. It required to subclass CALayer (lets' say AnimLayer) and define a protocol in it with just one method that stores the "state". This method has one parameter which is the state. Then I implemented the protocol method that stores the state in AnimLayer class and set the unique object as a delegate. So those presentation layers (AnimLayer copies) do not store the state themselves. Instead the "state" value passed as a parameter to the delegate function is stored by unique object in main thread.

I did something like that but my task was a bit different. I don't know the easier way, sorry. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Captures the basic idea. Although, in this case @Stultus needn't set up a delegate and code it in `animationDidStop:finished:`. He can implement the `finish:` block of his `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:finished:` method. The block has a `finished` argument which will tell him if the animation has been interrupted. Rest of it should be like you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

[@Grzegorz Krukowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43934498/7180430) worked like a charm for me. I just wanted to add that if you don't need to resume the animation from where it left off, but simulate it kept running on the background, you can simply omit these lines:

```
let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
self.beginTime = timeSincePause
```

from the `resume()` function in `CALayer` extension, and leave `beginTime` set to `0.0`.

Also, you can manually call `willResignActive` and `didBecomeActive` methods for animations you want to resume when `ViewController` disappears, even if the app didn't go to the background.

Answer (score 1):

This way will be better, just register on ApplicationDelegate will become methods and observer the status.

```
- (void)pauseAnimate{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [self.layer timeOffset];
    self.layer.speed = 1.0;
    self.layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    self.layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [self.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    self.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}

- (void)stopAnimate{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [self.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    self.layer.speed = 0.0;
    self.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}
```

Comment: Copied from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1673/_index.html but didn't mention it. The method name is also misleading

Answer (score 1):

This is my snippet to enable a `CALayer` to save and restore animations:

```swift
// CALayer+AnimationRestoration.swift

import QuartzCore

private enum AssociateKey {
  static var savedAnimations: UInt8 = 0
}

public extension CALayer {

  /// The saved animations to restore.
  private var savedAnimations: [String: CAAnimation] {
    get {
      if let current = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociateKey.savedAnimations) as? [String: CAAnimation] {
        return current
      } else {
        // lazy initialize
        let new: [String: CAAnimation] = [:]
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociateKey.savedAnimations, new, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        return new
      }
    }
    set {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociateKey.savedAnimations, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }
  }

  /// Save an animation.
  /// - Parameter key: The animation key for the animation to save.
  func saveAnimation(for key: String) {
    guard let animation = animation(forKey: key) else {
      assertionFailure("no animation for key: \(key) to save")
      return
    }

    assert(savedAnimations[key] == nil, "try to save a duplicated animation for key: \(key)")
    savedAnimations[key] = animation
  }

  /// Restore an animation saved before.
  /// - Parameter key: The animation key for the animation to restore.
  func restoreAnimation(for key: String) {
    guard let animation = savedAnimations[key] else {
      assertionFailure("no animation for key: \(key) to restore")
      return
    }

    add(animation, forKey: key)

    savedAnimations.removeValue(forKey: key)
  }

  /// Clears all saved animations.
  func resetSavedAnimations() {
    savedAnimations = [:]
  }
}
```

The idea is to use [Objective-C Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418865-objc_getassociatedobject) to add a dictionary on the animating layer to save animations before app entering background.

To use it:

```swift
// in UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification callback
animatingLayer.saveAnimation(for: "the-animation-key")

// in UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification callback
animatingLayer.restoreAnimation(for: "the-animation-key")
```

You'd better to call `saveAnimation(for:)` and `restoreAnimation(for:)` in pairs to keep the `savedAnimations` in a good state. Or you can call `resetSavedAnimations()` to clean it.

Comment: very impressive approach!

Answer (score 0):

As of the release of swift5.

It is also worth noting. That in some cases, you need to reset the animated property to get the new animation to stick. I can confirm this with an animated transformation.

Just calling...

```
view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

did not suffice, and new animation would not run. I also had to run...

```
view.transform = .identity
```

I suspect you might be able to set it to any new value or save the previous state and set it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't recall the exact details but I think you can get the current animated position of the frame by looking at the layer bounds and position property of your view. You could store those at app suspend and restore them when the app is in the foreground again.